# Layout stretching

Tags: android, layout

Is there a layout, that would allow me to make it in absolute values, but when it would be on larger / smaller screen, it would stretch and adjusted those values, to fit onto the screen  but preserve the same look?

Relative layout still keens on exact values.

For example, I have a button and I want it to have it the width of 1/3 of the screen of every device.

Answer (score 1):

Setting manualy in code the width of an element to (for example) screenWidth/3 works. Yet I don't think it's clean. But this technique works.

Answer (score 1):

Find device dimensions at runtime and set width of button at runtime.

```
Display mDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int deviceWidth = mDisplay.getWidth();
    int deviceHeight = mDisplay.getHeight();

button.getLayoutParams().width = deviceWidth / 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the values in `dpi` of your layout and view and they will adjust themselves on any screen

Comment: Is it required to use absolute layout then?

Comment: @ViliX Nup not required :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. When I run some layout with this technique used, it doesn't strech out.

Comment: @ViliX Then in that case you would have to do all the UI programatically, however i still beleive that `dpi` technique should work since it works on the density pixel of the device